# request.getParameter returns null in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Form.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Form</title>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000">

<h1>Please enter your details</h1>

<form name="RegistrationForm" action="NewUser" method="post">
    <table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td align="right">First Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="NewFirstName"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Last Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="NewLastName"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Email Address:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="EmailAddress"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Phone Number:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Phone Number"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Semester</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Semester"></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

NewUser.java(Servlet Class)

```
package com.seria.quiz;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class NewUser
 */
@WebServlet("/NewUser")
public class NewUser extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public NewUser() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        Connection conn = null;

        try {
            String FirstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
            System.out.println("Your firstname: " + FirstName);
            String LastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
            System.out.println("Your LastName: " + LastName);
            String Emailid = request.getParameter("email");
            String PhoneNumber = request.getParameter("phoneNumber");
            String Semester = request.getParameter("semester");

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/seriaquiz", "root", "root");
            PreparedStatement pst = (PreparedStatement) conn
                    .prepareStatement("insert into formdetails(firstName,lastName,email,phoneNumber,semester) values(?,?,?,?,?)");// try2
                                                                                                                                    // the
                                                                                                                                    // name
            pst.setString(1, FirstName);
            System.out.println("Your firstname1: " + FirstName);
            pst.setString(2, LastName);
            System.out.println("Your LastName1: " + LastName);
            pst.setString(3, Emailid);
            pst.setString(4, PhoneNumber);
            pst.setString(5, Semester);

            int i = pst.executeUpdate();
            String msg = " ";
            if (i != 0) {
                msg = "Record has been inserted";
                pw.println("<font size='6' color=blue>" + msg + "</font>");

            } else {
                msg = "failed to insert the data";
                pw.println("<font size='6' color=blue>" + msg + "</font>");
            }
            pst.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            pw.println(e);
        }

    }

}
```

As the title says request.getParameter is returning null every time. I put sysout statements after requestParameter, and it shows null value. Any help will be appreciated. Sorry for any inconvenience, I'm new here.

Comment: Try `request.getParameter("NewFirstName")` to match with the name specified in JSP for first name. OR change in jsp `<td><input type="text" name="firstName"></td>`

Comment: I can't believe that I was making that mistake but it worked! Thanks all you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter names in servlet need to match them in the JSP

so

```
String FirstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
```

should be

```
String FirstName = request.getParameter("NewFirstName");
```

Answer (score 0):

you are asking for wrong parameters 
you should always ask for same id/name as described in your html

```
request.getParameter("NewFirstName");
```

Answer (score 0):

From w3.org section **17.2 Controls**

> Users interact with forms through named **controls**.
>
> A control's "control name" is given by its **name** attribute. The scope of the name attribute for a
>   control within a FORM element is the FORM element.
>
> When a form is submitted for processing, some controls have their name paired with their current
>   value and these pairs are submitted with the form.

Example of control is your

```
<input type="text" name="NewFirstName">
```

So when the form gets submitted, it contains a **control name=value** e.g.

```
NewFirstName=YourFirstName
```

In your JSP, you should do access it using the the **control name**

```
String FirstName = request.getParameter("NewFirstName");
```

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html

Answer (score 0):

Get the exact value of a form parameter try this....

String FirstName = request.getParameter("NewFirstName");

because ..

you specify name attribute by 'NewFirstName'...